# ASP.net UI refresh issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a checkbox and a checkbox list in one of my web pages.

The UI is like

Color - Header Checkbox

Checkboxlist items are

Red

Green

Blue

Yellow

Complete selection  - clicking on the header checkbox selects/ deselects the entire checkbox list.

Partial selection of the checkbox list shows the header checkbox with a different background color to indicate partial selection.

I do a check for number of selected items in each of the checkbox list selection changes. In a client server environment, there is a time delay and if we make two continuous selections in the checkbox list, an update of the header control is done for the first selection and by the time UI is refreshed, the second selection is gone. 
I also implemented the above one using JavaScript but then also the behavior is same.
What could be an alternative for this?

Comment: I read it twice and still have no idea what you are talking about. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: which screen shot you are talking about?

Comment: need some more info. what are you trying to achieve? what's happening behind the scene (on checkbox click) etc.

Comment: You know you can edit your question? Then you can take out that reference to "attached screenshots", after you found out that you couldn't attach them. And maybe you can find some other way to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not particularly clear, but it sounds like you want some sort of three state check box? It also sounds like the postback is occurring and wiping out your second selection?

If so, there are some control options out there. Here's a link to one that may help. http://www.chadscharf.com/index.php/2008/10/3-state-checkbox-using-microsoft-ajax/

You really need to post some code and link to the screen shots you mention.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Yes I am trying to achieve something like the three state check box. I was not able to attach the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios you are trying to satisfy and the simpliest approach is utilising Javascript.  Certainly one direction is using Jquery to simplify the wiring of DOM elements together.

Following is an example that kinda covers the two scenarios.  One the top level control checks / unchecks all the elements.  Second, the individuals change the background of the top level element.  This is not drop and run code, it merely demonstrates the technique in isolation.  Changes and tweaks I've leave to you + if you're unfamiliar with Jquery: simply search each function on [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/) site.  Enjoy!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){       

            // Wire up the 'select-all' to the child elements
            $('#topLevel').bind('change' , function(){
                // Record this object
                var base = this;
                // Change the child elements
                $('#checkboxContainer input').each( function(){
                    $(this).attr('checked' , $(base).is(':checked'))
                })                  
            });

            // Make the individual checkbox selects alter the
            // background of the top-level wrapper
            $('#checkboxContainer input').bind('change' , function(){
                // Get a handle to the top item
                var topLevel = $('#topLevelWrapper');                   
                // Have we selected the item?
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    // Remove the previous class assignments
                    topLevel.attr('class' , '');
                    // Assign the current css class from the parent
                    topLevel.addClass( $(this).parent().attr('class') );                        
                }
            });

        })
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .Red{
            background-color:#F00;
        }
        .Green{
            background-color:#0F0;
        }
        .Blue{
            background-color:#00F;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="topLevelWrapper">
        <label for="topLevel">Top level selection</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="topLevel" />
    </div>

    <div id="checkboxContainer">
        <ul>
            <li class="Red">
                <label for="topLevel">Red</label>
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </li>
            <li class="Blue">
                <label for="topLevel">Blue</label>
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </li>
            <li class="Green">
                <label for="topLevel">Green</label>
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</body>
```